# Opencart Custom Description Design (Products)

Tags: html, css, opencart, product

I've just purchased and set up Pav Fila OpenCart theme. Looks like a great theme and the only thing I want to change is the product description layout (design).

Is this easily possible with the inner block builder and layout builder or needs advanced coding? Maybe an extention?

See what we have now: http://mika.shoes/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=46 and what we

I want a simple evenly distributed description rows/columns like in the product description in G-RAW: https://www.g-star.com/en_bg/shop/women/jackets_and_blazers/d11950-6541-89

Please, note that I am DESIGNER not coder but learning now and understanding everything as explained. Do not be too harsh with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want a simple layout change you can do this with opencart editor

Goto catalog > products > select your product ,click edit

Goto general tab

here you can customize your design like this-

[image]

Comment: Nah, this is a standart text editor. I want something more advanced like a block builder/visual composer style editor for the description. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok i got what you need,you could try   https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-builder-for-opencart/8825943  (a paid one)  or you could try   https://shopunity.net/extension/visual-designer  (a free one)

Comment: You have one beer from me! That works perfectly! THANKS!